# Шифрование с помощью таблицы Виженера

Tags: c#

Задали написать программу, которая шифрует и дешифрует текст с помощью таблицы Виженера. Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием кода.

Comment: Введите в поиск в гугле следующую строку:

    алгоритм Виженера c#

Получите полную страницу результатов, включая архив с готовым кодом, описание алгоритма и даже видеоинструкцию.

Comment: @_Win_32, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. А тех кто все таки отвечает - забанить мало :). Ибо они тоже косвенно нарушают правила форума.

Comment: @Darix, а код-то от @Spectre и правда хорош (боюсь не для начинающих). Если учащийся (о заданиях для которых Вы так беспокоитесь) **реально разберется, как он работает**, то пользы ему будет больше, чем от самостоятельно вымученной программки.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нашёл среди старых лаб, метод шифрования:

```
_alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

private static int IndexNormalizer(int count, int index)
{
        return index >= 0
                      ? index - count * (index / count) // + 
                      : count + index + count * (-(index + 1) / count);//+
}
//шифр Виженера
string VigenereEncrypt(string text, string key, bool flag)
{
     return new string(text.Select((ch, idx) => _alph[IndexNormalizer(_alph.Length,  _alph.IndexOf(ch) + _alph.IndexOf(key[IndexNormalizer(key.Length, idx)])*(flag ? 1 : -1))]).ToArray());
}
```

**UPD:** я просто поражен "компактностью" кода, к которой я когда-то так стремился.

Comment: ch, idx, что они значат?

Comment: символ и его индекс в строке